# Typescript Interface string is accepting a number from a fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fetch

I am loading data from a fetch in TS and attempting to set a value which should be a string but instead is a number.

The interface

```
export default interface IPost {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  user_id: string;
}
```

My attempt at loading the values from the fetch

```
.then((data: IPost[]) => {
  console.log("POST DATA", data);
  const posts = data.map((p: IPost) => {
    const post: IPost = {
      id: p.id,
      title: p.title,
      content: p.content,
      imageUrl: p.imageUrl,
      user_id: p.user_id //thinks its a string but its actually a number
      //need to fix this for now just make it a string
    }
    console.log('post map', post, typeof post.user_id)
    return post
  })
})
```

When I `console.log` the `user_id` it is a number even though the interface requires a string. What I have tried is replacing `user_id: p.user_id` with `user_id: p.user_id.toString()`. This does work but I wondered why does TS accept a number as a string shouldn't it throw an error or not accept the value.
Thanks

Comment: Use `.then((data: unknown) => {…})` instead if you don't know (or trust) what value the API actually returns

Comment: You are defining the interace and stating that `user_id` is a string. If the API instead sends a number it's not the responsibility of TS to fix the data to fit your type. It's your responsibility to fix your type to fit the data, or somehow convert your data to match your type

Comment: So even though i set a type of string it allowed a number is this expected the behavior? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `typeof p.user_id` returns `number` and not `string`?

Comment: Typescript doesn't provide and kind of type control or casting at runtime; it only ensures internal consistency of the code at compile time. APIs can still send data which doesn't conform to a declared interface, and it is your job to validate and conform it to your interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the official docs said:

> TypeScript adds additional syntax to JavaScript to support a tighter
> integration with your editor. Catch errors early in your editor.

This means type checker is only used when you're coding, but not the real runtime. In your code, the `data` from fetch, is not real `IPost[]` as expected, you should better change your code as following.

```
export interface IFetchPost {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  content: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  user_id: number; // the original user_id type is number
}

export interface IPost extends Omit<IFetchPost, 'user_id'> {
  user_id: string; // convert to string
}
```

and fetch:

```
.then((data: IFetchPost[]) => {
  console.log("POST DATA", data);
  const posts = data.map((p: IFetchPost) => {
    const post: IPost = {
      id: p.id,
      title: p.title,
      content: p.content,
      imageUrl: p.imageUrl,
      user_id: String(p.user_id)
    }
    console.log('post map', post, typeof post.user_id)
    return post
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const post: IPost = {
  id: p.id,
  title: p.title,
  content: p.content,
  imageUrl: p.imageUrl,
  user_id: String(p.user_id)
}
```

Comment: This is what I already did but I was just wondering how it was able to accept a number as a string. I did typeof p.user_id and it was a number after being stored.

Comment: `p.user_id` is still `number` as we are converting `post. user_id`

Answer (score 0):

Actually this isn't about ts. But if you wanna convert your data to string you should use `toString()` or `String(p.user_id)`

Comment: It *is* about TS. Should TS not be type safe and throw an error? That's what Mark asks. He doesn't ask for a solution.

Comment: oh I see. So sorry Mark. I thought this is a bug question.